# A special case of XML generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm working with SQL Server 2012 SP1 Express:

How can I generate this XML?

```
<Batch CodeGeneratorId="1234" BatchNumber="Batch0001" OrderNumber="Order0001" TimeStamp="2012-01-01 05:15:00">
    <BatchDetail Key="Name" Value="MyName" />
    <BatchDetail Key="Stu" Value="FA20123.01" />
    <BatchDetail Key="Com_L1" Value="19898" />
    <BatchDetail Key="Dec_L1" Value="24" />
    <BatchDetail Key="Agg_L1" Value="18520" />
</Batch>
```

Using the data on `BATCH_DATA` table:

```
ID  |          Key     |    Value
----+------------------+-------------
1   | CodeGeneratorId  | 1234
2   | BatchNumber      | Batch0001
3   | OrderNumber      | Order0001
4   | Name             | MyName
5   | Stu              | FA20123.01
6   | Com_L1           | 19898
7   | Dec_L1           | 24
8   | Agg_L1           | 18520
```

My problem is that I don't know how to generate this part:

```
<Batch CodeGeneratorId="1234" BatchNumber="Batch0001" 
       OrderNumber="Order0001" TimeStamp="2012-01-01 05:15:00">
```

Comment: What if you have more than one row where the key is `CodeGeneratorId`, or `BatchNumber` etc?

Comment: No, `CodeGeneratorId`, `BatchNumber`, etc. are going to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn your table into XML and then query that XML to build your desired XML.

```sql
select T.X.value('(/row[Key = "CodeGeneratorId"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [@CodeGeneratorId],
       T.X.value('(/row[Key = "BatchNumber"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [@BatchNumber],
       T.X.value('(/row[Key = "OrderNumber"]/Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [@OrderNumber],
       sysdatetime() as [@TimeStamp],
       (
       select R.X.value('(Key/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [@Name],
              R.X.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') as [@Value]
       from T.X.nodes('row') as R(X)
       where R.X.value('(Key/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)') not in ('CodeGeneratorId', 'BatchNumber', 'OrderNumber')
       for xml path('BatchDetail'), type
       )
from (
     select [Key],
            Value
     from T
     for xml path('row'), type
     ) as T(X)
for xml path('Batch'), type
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ca2c/2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to show also TimeStamp after OrderNumber. Maybe using `SYSDATETIME ( )`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the following to output in the format you required:

```
CREATE TABLE #T ([ID] INT, [Key] VARCHAR(15), [Value] VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #T ([ID], [Key], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'CodeGeneratorId', '1234'),
    (2, 'BatchNumber', 'Batch0001'),
    (3, 'OrderNumber', 'Order0001'),
    (4, 'Name', 'MyName'),
    (5, 'Stu', 'FA20123.01'),
    (6, 'Com_L1', '19898'),
    (7, 'Dec_L1', '24'),
    (8, 'Agg_L1', '18520');


SELECT  [Batch].[CodeGeneratorId], 
        [Batch].[BatchNumber], 
        [Batch].[OrderNumber], 
        BatchDetails.[Key], 
        BatchDetails.Value
FROM    (   SELECT  [CodeGeneratorId], [BatchNumber], [OrderNumber]
            FROM    (   SELECT  [Key], [Value]
                        FROM    #T
                        WHERE   [Key] IN ('CodeGeneratorId', 'BatchNumber', 'OrderNumber')
                    ) t
                    PIVOT 
                    (   MAX(Value)
                        FOR [Key] IN ([CodeGeneratorId], [BatchNumber], [OrderNumber])
                    ) pvt
        ) AS [Batch]
        CROSS JOIN
        (   SELECT  [Key], Value
            FROM    #T AS BatchDetail 
            WHERE   [Key] NOT IN ('CodeGeneratorId', 'BatchNumber', 'OrderNumber')
        ) AS BatchDetails
FOR XML AUTO;
```

It is essentially a two stage process, first create your headers:

```
SELECT  [CodeGeneratorId], [BatchNumber], [OrderNumber]
FROM    (   SELECT  [Key], [Value]
            FROM    #T
            WHERE   [Key] IN ('CodeGeneratorId', 'BatchNumber', 'OrderNumber')
        ) t
        PIVOT 
        (   MAX(Value)
            FOR [Key] IN ([CodeGeneratorId], [BatchNumber], [OrderNumber])
        ) pvt
FOR XML AUTO;
```

Will give:

```
<pvt CodeGeneratorId="1234" BatchNumber="Batch0001" OrderNumber="Order0001" />


SELECT  [Key], Value
FROM    #T AS BatchDetail 
WHERE   [Key] NOT IN ('CodeGeneratorId', 'BatchNumber', 'OrderNumber')
FOR XML AUTO;
```

Will give:

```
<BatchDetail Key="Name" Value="MyName" />
<BatchDetail Key="Stu" Value="FA20123.01" />
<BatchDetail Key="Com_L1" Value="19898" />
<BatchDetail Key="Dec_L1" Value="24" />
<BatchDetail Key="Agg_L1" Value="18520" />
```

So it is then just a matter of combining the two. This may need to be turned from a cross join to a cross apply, if you actually have a field to link on:

```
CREATE TABLE #T2 ([ID] INT, Col INT, [Key] VARCHAR(15), [Value] VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #T2 ([ID], Col, [Key], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'CodeGeneratorId', '1234'),
    (2, 1, 'BatchNumber', 'Batch0001'),
    (3, 1, 'OrderNumber', 'Order0001'),
    (4, 1, 'Name', 'MyName'),
    (5, 1, 'Stu', 'FA20123.01'),
    (6, 1, 'Com_L1', '19898'),
    (7, 1, 'Dec_L1', '24'),
    (8, 1, 'Agg_L1', '18520'),
    (9, 2, 'CodeGeneratorId', '1255'),
    (10, 2, 'BatchNumber', 'Batch0002'),
    (11, 2, 'OrderNumber', 'Order0002'),
    (12, 2, 'Name', 'MyName'),
    (13, 2, 'Stu', 'FA20123.01'),
    (14, 2, 'Com_L1', '19898'),
    (15, 2, 'Dec_L1', '24'),
    (16, 2, 'Agg_L1', '18520');


SELECT  [Batch].[CodeGeneratorId], 
        [Batch].[BatchNumber], 
        [Batch].[OrderNumber], 
        BatchDetails.[Key], 
        BatchDetails.Value
FROM    (   SELECT  Col, [CodeGeneratorId], [BatchNumber], [OrderNumber]
            FROM    (   SELECT  Col, [Key], [Value]
                        FROM    #T2
                        WHERE   [Key] IN ('CodeGeneratorId', 'BatchNumber', 'OrderNumber')
                    ) t
                    PIVOT 
                    (   MAX(Value)
                        FOR [Key] IN ([CodeGeneratorId], [BatchNumber], [OrderNumber])
                    ) pvt
        ) AS [Batch]
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  [Key], Value
            FROM    #T2 AS BatchDetail 
            WHERE   [Key] NOT IN ('CodeGeneratorId', 'BatchNumber', 'OrderNumber')
            AND     BatchDetail.Col = Batch.Col
        ) AS BatchDetails
FOR XML AUTO;
```

Will give you your two results:

```
<Batch CodeGeneratorId="1234" BatchNumber="Batch0001" OrderNumber="Order0001">
  <BatchDetails Key="Name" Value="MyName" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Stu" Value="FA20123.01" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Com_L1" Value="19898" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Dec_L1" Value="24" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Agg_L1" Value="18520" />
</Batch>
<Batch CodeGeneratorId="1255" BatchNumber="Batch0002" OrderNumber="Order0002">
  <BatchDetails Key="Name" Value="MyName" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Stu" Value="FA20123.01" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Com_L1" Value="19898" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Dec_L1" Value="24" />
  <BatchDetails Key="Agg_L1" Value="18520" />
</Batch>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to show also TimeStamp after OrderNumber. Maybe using `SYSDATETIME ( )`. How can I do it?